# Using Go to write a library for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, c, gcc, arm, go

I'm considering using Go as a low-level, performant language alternative to C/Objective-C to implement a library for an iPhone App. Could either of the Go compilers generate a library that could be linked into a native iPhone app with the Go runtime, etc.? Is there an ARM port for Go or does gccgo/gcc support this? I imagine that since gccgo uses gcc as the back-end and Xcode uses gcc to compile iPhone apps that there is a strong chance that this is possible. If it's possible, how would I set that up in an Xcode project?

Has anyone tried this or seen it discussed before? (When I do a Google search like "compiling go code iphone" the "go" part is completely unused and I get only stuff about iPhone development.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go doesn't support the iphone platform right now, but it does support ARM processors. There hasn't been much discussion about this on the mailing list though.

Answer (score 2):

Even if possible, I suspect Go is significantly slower than C or Objective C.  Most independent benchmarks seem to suggest poor performance using the current development versions.  These [microbenchmarks against C suggest](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=go&lang2=gcc) Go is 2 to 150 times slower than C.  It is even slower than Java and C# Mono.  So I see little reason to call Go a performant alternative.

Although it depends on your application, I suspect leveraging the GPU api is the best bet for most performance problems.

Comment: So Go is targeting replacing C#/Java on the server? Is that sort of the idea? I guess C will do what I need, but I could use the strings, hashtables, etc.

Comment: Is interesting also to look at the code size column 150X but 624 (Go) vs 2579 (C). You develop faster and in the time your application becomes successful also the compiler could have improved.

Comment: >> Go is 2 to 150 times slower than C << The nice thing about boxplot charts is that you can easily see 150 is an outlier http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php?gcc=on&go=on&calc=chart

Comment: >> These microbenchmarks << Are for the 6g Go compiler and runtime, but the OP was talking about gccgo

Answer (score 2):

One thing to at least look at would be Lua. It is fast and is a language I like using. [iPhone Wax](http://www.mobileorchard.com/announcing-iphone-wax-native-uikit-iphone-apps-written-in-lua/) uses lua.

Comment: I just read the reference manual this week! What I'm actually implementing is a scripting language and the Lua C sources could be useful although implementing a scripting language in another scripting language would probably be a bad idea. (My prototype for the scripting language is in Haskell and I was looking for an adequate substitute. I will probably have to make due with C.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using Wax. From February 2015, all new submitted apps will require a 64-bit chunk. iPhone Wax has no 64-bit support, and adding it would require fixes to the parameter marshalling between lua and objc-c, in both directions - something that already has bugs in 32-bit (unsigned ints don't work properly).

Answer (score 0):

The [Go Mobile](https://github.com/golang/mobile) project now has some support for IOS and Android mobile development. See the wiki section on [Building for IOS](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile#building-and-deploying-to-ios) for details for your application.